# docker: is it possible to run containers from an other container?

Tags: python, linux, docker

I am running a dockerized python web application that has to run long tasks on certain requests (i.e. running some R scripts taking around 1 minute to complete). At the moment I put everything in one container and I am just running it just like this.

However, I think that it would be faster and cleaner to separate this 'background web app' and the R scripts one process = one container). I was therefore wondering if there is **a way to run a container from within an other container** (i.e being able to call `docker run [...]` on the host from the already-dockerized web application).

I tried to search for it and found some useful information on linking containers together, but in my case I'd more be interested in being able to create single-use containers on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite like this solution: [Run docker inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239116/run-docker-inside-a-docker-container) which basically allows you to use docker that's running on the host.

But if you really want to run docker in docker, here is the official solution using the `dind` image: https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/

Comment: This is exactly what I want, be able to call the docker of the host. I will give a try to this solution and let you know how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Creating 'R script' containers on the fly worked like a charm with the first answer you provided. Thanks again.