# Docker Inside a Docker on Windows

Tags: docker, windows-7, docker-container

I have seen docker inside docker docker container for Ubuntu/Linux. As per the replies in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239116/run-docker-inside-a-docker-container), the following command works

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/bin/docker [your image`

Are there any similar commands available for docker in Windows 7?

Comment: This example doesn't run docker in docker. 
It copies docker client into the container and allows it to control host's docker. I.e. this is a container escape allowing to control a service on the host, not having docker server inside of the container.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am using the below command in Windows 10 to run docker inside docker. The docker image is with alpine OS. Note that the path is `//var/run/docker.sock`

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --name dockerindocker -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker

/ # docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
02285c22006f        docker              "docker-entrypoint..."   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            dockerindocker

/ # cat /etc/alpine-release
3.6.2
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for me in PowerShell. Under Git bash it leaves without any error message or Docker event (`docker ev$`)

Comment: The problem this fixes is that `bash` on Windows automatically converts paths to Windows format, even when they aren't real local paths. Doubling the slash at the start of the path "escapes" it from this automatic conversion. The double slash in the path is not necessary when running in `cmd.exe` or Powershell, as those shells do not perform this conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Windows doesn't support true docker-in-docker yet.

All the answers here are about running a docker client in a container which connects to the top level docker server on the host (same docker running the container where you invoke docker from). It is not a real docker in docker.

See discussion here for more details https://github.com/docker-library/docker/issues/49